# React-i18n showing json property labels before rendering the translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, translation

I am trying to add react-i18n to my React app - with caching in the browser.
All is fine, I have added it - it works. Problem is that in the moment I am accessing the website/app, for around 0.2s I can see all the property labels from the translation json (which is on public/locale). Any idea about how to make the website "wait" for the properties to be feteched into their translation - or how to fix this?
I am attaching here the configuration file for i18n and an image with the issue. Bear in mind it's for 0.2s - after that all works fine (until refreshing the page when again 0.2s I can see the labels)

Thanks!

Configuration file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import ChainedBackend from "i18next-chained-backend";
import HttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LocalStorageBackend from "i18next-localstorage-backend";
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  .use(ChainedBackend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
      wait: false,
    },
    backend: {
      backends: [
        LocalStorageBackend,
        HttpBackend
      ],
      backendOptions: [{
        expirationTime: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 7 days
      },
      {
        loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'
      }]
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Image with the issue (of small amount of time):
[image: Image with the issue (of small amount of time):]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not using Suspense, and/or not waiting for the ready flag to be true: https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc#not-using-suspense